# How do I dynamically making a printf statement?

Tags: java, mysql

The printf statement can look something like `System.out.printf("%-30s", "Scientific Name")`. Meanwhile, I've tasked myself with creating a text-based interface for querying a mysql database.

A line of code I've got is `format.append("%-"+ name.length()+6);`, where `format` is a StringBuilder, and `name.length()` is the length of the column that's being looped through, because I have no way of knowing ahead of time how big the column is. I don't even know of the database, nor what it contains, ahead of time.

Here's the issue though: that comma between the strings. That's not a part of a string, itself, is it? I mean, it's text. It has to be, right? I just need to add `\"` where `printf` normally has quotations, yes?

...but I've never needed something like that when I've plugged a `StringBuilder` in to something before.

EDIT:

Basically, I want to be able to go `.printf(format , column name , column name , column name , ...)`, where `format` is the format for the entire table that's to be printed out (and thus reused). Is that possible?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail as to what you currently are seeing as output? and what you would like to see as output?

Comment: I edited the question at the bottom.  It should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should put your printf command into a loop.  This will print all the columns on the same line,  but you can build each. If you are printing to a file you will likely need to drop a comma in there at some point, so keep an eye on the first character that prints out and remove it.

```
for(loop through column names){
    System.out.printf(",%-"+namelength()+"s", name);
}
```

Comment: Yup. It works exactly as I needed. God. I'm using StringBuilder too much. I completely forgot that you can print lines piece by piece instead of figuring it out all in one go. (This was not me being lazy. This was me finally getting the guy to actually test the code as the database doesn't work on my computers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.printf(format, column name, ...)` because the commas are just part of giving the `printf` function the parameters it needs, not part of the actual text you want printed.